# How do I import contacts from a vcf file on ubuntu-touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How do I import contacts from a vcf (vCard) file or google to ubuntu phone. I tried this command:

```
syncevolution --sync one-way-from-server Google_Contacts addresbook
```

but it fails with the error `[ERROR] no such source(s): addressbook'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure it to know to ping your account first. This was posted on another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360554/how-do-i-sync-google-contacts) on the subject.

```
syncevolution --configure --sync-property "username=email@gmail.com" --sync-property "password=secret" Google_Contacts
```

I don't want to patronize, but keep in mind that you need to replace the "email" in "username=email@gmail.com" with your gmail pseudonym, and "secret" in "password=secret" with your actual password.

I just did this as I was typing and the following commands imported my contacts:

```
adb shell
sudo -u phablet -i
syncevolution --configure --sync-property "username=email@gmail.com" --sync-property "password=secret" Google_Contacts
syncevolution --sync refresh-from-server Google_Contacts addressbook
syncevolution --sync one-way-from-server Google_Contacts addressbook
```