# Google contacts sync on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contacts

Why doesn't google contacts synchronization work on my Ubuntu touch?

Is there is another way to copy my contacts? I saved it on my SIM card but there are no options to show my SIM's contacts

How should I proceed?

Comment: There are options to sync your contacts. Check the links 


  http://askubuntu.com/questions/360466/ubuntu-touch-officially-launched-version-how-to-sync-contacts and 
  http://askubuntu.com/questions/360554/how-do-i-sync-google-contacts

Answer (score 1):

You can use syncevolution to sync your contacts by installing it from repo

> sudo apt-get install syncevolution syncevolution-provider-uoa