# How do I sync contacts with my online account?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contacts

I've just got my new Ubuntu Touch, how do I import my contacts if I have them saved in my Google account?

Comment: please try to search first before posting a question. It has been answered before.http://askubuntu.com/questions/360554/how-do-i-sync-google-contacts `or` http://askubuntu.com/questions/360466/ubuntu-touch-officially-launched-version-how-to-sync-contacts

Answer (score 1):

The first time you open the Contacts app you’ll be asked if you want to sync contacts with your Google account. If you have answered “no” but change your mind later, you can do so by going to the Today scope, and setting up your Google account there. After that you can sync your contacts (and, if you want, calendar events as well).